# what version of the Eclipse RCP we need to upgrade to along with Java 8

Tags: eclipse-rcp, java-8

what version of the Eclipse RCP we need to upgrade to along with Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Luna (4.4) is the first to fully support Java 8. This is the current version available from the [Eclipse site](http://www.eclipse.org/)